# Eclipse stops Recognizing object (Android)

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, android-view

I already tried to find some answer for this but unfortunately I couldn't. I am trying to teach myself Android. Apparently, for no reason, Eclipse stops recognizing a variable between one line and the next one.

I have a class that extends a View (a custom View). I am getting this error on the onDraw (sorry, can't post image)

```
public void onDraw(Canvas c) {
    c.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher), 0, 0, null);
    c.Rotate(-10);
}
```

The drawBitmap line is not recognized as error. If I go after the . in the drawBitmap line and press Ctrl+Space, I get just the Java.Object functions (Equals, hashCode, etc) and not the Canvas'. The c.Rotate line is marked as error - if I open c. the autocomplete does not recognize anything but the basic object functions (no draw, rotate, get/set, etc);
If I try to use the variable before the DrawBitmap, it also won't recognize.

The weird thing is: if I keep just the drawBitmap line, it compiles and runs fine.

What could it be?

EDIT:
Eclipse
Version: 3.7.2
Build id: M20120208-0800

Android Development Toolkit
Version: 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534

Build Target: Android 2.2 (Rev 8)

SOLUTION:
I just had to go into the workspace folder and delete the .Metadata, and re-add the project. I don't know what caused this error, but it got fixed. For more information, please check the first answer. If someone knows what happened, I would find it very interesting to understand what happened.

Comment: have you copied project from some site or somewhere else ?

Answer (score 2):

should be lowercase `rotate`

```
c.rotate(-10);
```

the rest is very mysterious

Comment: Eclipse sometimes failes to give you syntax completion if there is an error in your code (e.g. when it does no longer know the type of `c`). And sometimes it might need a restart.

Comment: The rotate thing was correct - changing to rotate in lowercase helped it. However, it still seems to be unable to know the type of c. Already tried restarting, but it did not fix the bug. Any extra clues of why it stops "knowing" the type of c? I even tried changing the name of the variable.

Comment: I just pasted the code, with the case fix and when I typed c. and hit command space (on Mac) it did seem to understand what I was doing. you're importing the right Canvas class, right? not that I can imagine it working at all without android.graphics.Canvas

Comment: Yes, I am importing. It is compiling and running, even though Eclipse does not recognize the type of the object.

Comment: if you hover your cursor over any of the `c` variables (or whatever you renamed it to) does it tell you anything? in my eclipse it says "Canvas c - com.mydomain.myproject.MyClass.onDraw(Canvas)"

Comment: Canvas c - com.enrico.Game1.GameScreen.onDraw(Canvas) too. I'll add specific version information on the question.

Comment: oh yeah, it is ctrl on mac, too. anyway, so it looks like your eclipse knows the variable. what if you make `c` a local variable and rename the parameter, so other code doesn't turn red, and then try ctrl-space after `c.` where `c` is the local

Comment: Weird, not only did it not fix it, it also didn't find Canvas to auto-complete when declaring the variable. Apparently, my Eclipse stopped to recognize the Android Package. Is there any known way to make the auto-complete rebuild its information?

Comment: well there's always Project menu -> Clean

Comment: This just cleans the Project executables... I found that I could run eclipse -clean from the command line and it would clean some stuff but also no help. Damn, this is so annoying because it literally stopped worked between one line and the next haha

Comment: do you have other methods with a Canvas parameter? or other variables of other types?

Comment: Yes, tried even another open project (Hello World) open at the same time, still getting the same issue. Eclipse stopped recognizing android all together, not even the auto-import works anymore. I am thinking of uninstalling ADT and reinstalling it.

Comment: Still not working. I guess I should give up for today. I don't have the slightest idea why it is not working.